# Update TTF Texture for Score

Tags: c++, sdl2, ttf

I have a little problem with Updating my Score with TTF. 
Im a neewbie so dont blame me :P

I Try to Update my Score But the Buffer Get too small after a while and my Game Crashes.

```
    void CText::Init(const string &_text, int xPos, int yPos, int Width, int Height)
{
    m_Text = _text;
    Font = TTF_OpenFont("arial.ttf", 30);

    SDL_Surface *pTempt = TTF_RenderText_Solid(Font, m_Text.c_str(), color);
    Texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(m_Renderer, pTempt);



    m_xPos = xPos;
    m_yPos = yPos;

    m_Rect.x = xPos;
    m_Rect.y = yPos;
    m_Rect.w = Width;
    m_Rect.h = Height;
    SDL_FreeSurface(pTempt);
}

void CText::RenderScore(int Score)
{
    sprintf_s(Buffer, "Score: %i", Score);
    SDL_Surface *pTempt = TTF_RenderText_Solid(Font, Buffer, color);
    Texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(m_Renderer, pTempt);
    SDL_RenderCopy(m_Renderer, Texture, NULL, &m_Rect);
    SDL_FreeSurface(pTempt);
}


//Game Loop 
if (lastscore != currentscore)
        {
            m_Text->Destroy(); //<-- This is SDL_DestroyTexture(Texture);
            lastscore = currentscore;
        }else{
        m_Text->RenderScore(currentscore);}
```

It shows my score and Updetes it too but I have my char Buffer[50] and after a while it runs out of memory. And i free my font and texture in the destructor.

I thank everybody who helps me out there

Comment: Is the score bigger than 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000?

Answer (score 3):

Every time you call `RenderScore`, you leak an `SDL_Texture` by not calling `SDL_DestroyTexture(Texture)` before reallocating it with `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface`.